# Trying to connect with PHP to remote SQL Server. Error "No connection could be made"

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I am trying to to insert data from PHP form to a remote SQL Server database.

When I clicked on a button submit get an error:

> *Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\wamp64\www\connection\connection.php on line 30*
>
> And an error: *Connection could not be established. Array ( [0] =>
>   Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5701 [code] => 5701
>   [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed
>   database context to 'Workflow'. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'Workflow'.
>   ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 5703 [code]
>   => 5703 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english. [message] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language
>   setting to us_english. ) )*

I have installed ODBC driver.

Connection.php:

```
<?php   
$servername = "server_ip"; 
$connectionInfo=array( "Database"=>"Workflow", "UID"=>"admin", 
"PWD"=>"pass");
$conn=sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectionInfo);

 $ID = $_POST['id'];
 $Date = $_POST['date'];


        $sql = "INSERT INTO T1 (ID,Date) VALUES ('$ID','$Date')";

 if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br/>";
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }


if(!mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
echo 'Data not inserted';
} else {
echo 'Data inserted';
}

?>
```

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="connection.php" method="post">
            <div class="container">
            ID: <input type="text" name="id">
                        Date: <input type="text" name="date">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="insert">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you connecting to a SQL-Server with a mysql interface. Which one do you have? Also read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @danblack I have my database on SQL Server on a remote machine. I want to make a php form that sends data to the table in SQL Server. I have setup WAMP on a local pc to host my website with PHP form. Should i choose different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use functions from two different PHP extensions - `sqlsrv_` and `mysqli_`. To connect to MS SQL Server, use `sqlsrv_` functions, they are part of [PHP Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

Also, consider the following:

- use prepared statements:
- surround columns names with `[]`, if they are reserved keywords

Try with this `connection.php`:

```
<?php   
# Connection
$servername = "server_ip"; 
$connectionInfo = array(
    "Database"=>"Workflow", 
    "UID"=>"admin", 
    "PWD"=>"pass"
);
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}

# Parameters
$id = $_POST['id'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$params = array(&$id, &$date);

# Statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO T1 (ID, [Date]) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, $params);
if ($stmt === false) {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_prepare): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    exit;
}
if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {
    echo "Statement executed.\n";
} else {
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_execute): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
}

# End
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
?>
```